# performing a number of operations with a single function

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe and I need to agregate it. I do it this way.

```
df
      .groupBy($"key1", $"key2")
      .agg(
        sum($"total_in").as("total_in")
        , sum($"val1_in").as("val1_in")
        , sum($"val2_in").as("val2_in")
        , sum($"val3_in").as("val3_in")
        , sum($"val4_in").as("val4_in")
        , sum($"total_out").as("total_out")
        , sum($"val1_out").as("val1_out")
        , sum($"val2_out").as("val2_out")
        , sum($"val3_out").as("val3_out")
        , sum($"val4_out").as("val4_out"))
```

It doesn't look all that bad, but if the number of operation in `agg` becomes larger or a `case when` or some other logic gets added to every `sum`, this code will look really cumbersome.

I know it can be done. Maybe passing the columns to a function and iterating other them. Something like

```
.agg(
  map(x => func())
)
```

but this is where I'm stuck. How do I pass only the columns I need? Is it possible to alias them in the same place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this :

```
val aggExpresion =
    df.columns
      .filterNot(Seq("key1","key2").contains(_))
      .map(s => sum(col(s)).as(s))

df.agg(aggExpresion.head,aggExpresion.tail:_*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *vararg* syntax:

In python:

```py
cols = ['total_in', 'val1_in', 'val2_in', ...]
.agg(*(sum(col).alias(col) for col in cols))
```

In Scala:

```scala
cols = Seq("total_in", "val1_in", "val2_in", ...)
.agg(
  sum(col(cols.head)).as(cols.head), 
  cols.tail.map(x => sum(col(x)).as(x)): _*
)
```